# Is there any where 2 datasets can be merged without one common variable in r

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames;

```
#df1 = sales_date
product.name <- c("dap","npk","urea","npk","dap","npk")
date.of.sale <- c("2020-07-03","2020-07-15","2020-07-09","2020-07-03","2020-07-20","2020-07-13")
sales_date <- data.frame(product.name,date.of.sale)

#df2 = week_names
week.name <-  c("21A01","21A02","21A02","21A04")
start.date <- c("2020-07-03","2020-07-10","2020-07-17","2020-07-24")
end.date <-  c("2020-07-09","2020-07-16","2020-07-23","2020-07-30")
week_names <- data.frame(week.name,start.date,end.date)
```

Question: I want to add the week.name to the first dataset (df1) with a condition that date.of.sale is between start.date and end.date.

I tried ifelse (to assign start.date and end.date manually) but as these are big data sets, it's a headache. Any recommendations of an easy way would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [non-equi joins with `data.tables`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/talks/ArunSrinivasanUseR2016.pdf), it's very efficient on big data sets :

```
library(data.table)

# Convert data.frame to data.table
setDT(sales_date)
setDT(week_names)

# Non-equi joins only possible on numerical values : convert character to Date
week_names[,c('start.date','end.date'):=.(as.Date(start.date),as.Date(end.date))]
sales_date[,date.of.sale:=as.Date(date.of.sale)]

# Non-equi join
week_names[sales_date,.(product.name,date.of.sale=i.date.of.sale,week.name),on=.(start.date <= date.of.sale, end.date > date.of.sale)]
```

```
#>    product.name date.of.sale week.name
#> 1:          dap   2020-07-03     21A01
#> 2:          npk   2020-07-15     21A02
#> 3:         urea   2020-07-09      <NA>
#> 4:          npk   2020-07-03     21A01
#> 5:          dap   2020-07-20     21A02
#> 6:          npk   2020-07-13     21A02
```